# Visual Studio AVD Settings for a Samsung Galaxy S10

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing a Xamarin app for a client and I am testing on a number of different devices and the application displays fine. These devices include a Samsung Galaxy Note 8, OnePlus 5 and OnePlus 3.

The client has a Samsung Galaxy S10 and appears to be having UI issues with the app - can anyone recommend AVD settings I can use in Visual Studio to get as close to a real Samsung Galaxy S10 as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't emulate physical device with AVD from Google. You can only emulate stock Android from Google. To run on real devices, look at Firebase Test Lab: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab

Comment: Are you talking to me? Question author should rather mark it

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake.